# Best Light for Reading, Computer Office: Flat Panel or Dome/Global Light

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, light-fixture

We are thinking of installing new ceiling lights, in Standard 10 feet ceiling. We originally have 4 inch diameter light in the hallway. My son would keep the door open to prevent getting hot, however this hallway light was hitting the side, peripheral of his eye, very small and lot of light would radiate from a small point, and it would hurt eyes.

I was looking into two other options.

a) A Larger Diameter commercial light (11 inches)

[image]

b) Or a Dome Global Light:
we will get 11 inch version, it has around 3 inch height

[image]

Just curious, whats good for lighting ergonomics,  a Flat led light or a Globe/Dome light? I know they have flat ceiling lights in offices, however a Global Light may have more surface area, and may radiate better. Maybe someone who's installed lighting in homes/offices would know.

---

Note: My ceiling does not have height thickness to put a recessed light in a recessed fixture.

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-11-in-12-5W-Dimmable-White-Integrated-LED-Edge-Lit-Round-Flat-Panel-Flush-Mount-Ceiling-Light-with-Color-Changing-CCT-74210-HD/301757622

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Hampton-Bay-9-in-2-Light-White-Mushroom-Flush-Mount-RS1951204/310507070

Comment: Close the door partially to block the direct view of the light, but not block airflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do not use lights that have the bulb (or tube) exposed. That bulb will put a shinny spot on the computer screen.

Try a recessed bulb in a recessed fixture, like this one:

https://www.build.com/product/summary/1499651?uid=3513755&jmtest=gg-gbav2_3513755&inv=1&&source=gg-gba-pla_3513755!c1710656546!a75290221828!dm!ng&gclid=CjwKCAiArbv_BRA8EiwAYGs23HrTE3bSCYbvezHtce-yRTmyFcPMvnGk93TFfGSOx68AzlEHzSsG9BoCyUYQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds

Computer screens are getting better nowadays, but a bright bulb will still be a problem due to reflection off the screen.

Comment: just a note, my ceiling does not have height thickness to put a recessed light in a recessed fixture, I wanted to try that option originally, its not the computer monitor, but the light coming out of the small ceiling light etc

Comment: both the 2 options I am looking at, seem it does not have bulb exposed, but a lens diffuser on top, looking at the pictures

Comment: Can you build a decorative box to hang down on your 10’ ceiling?

Comment: Btw, cutting a hole in the ceiling can cause sound transmission issues if you have a room “above”. Oh, and don’t forget that sound can travel both directions.